# I need a regex that matches a new line character not preceeded by two spaces, without lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's a sentence.

`Hello world.\nHello world.`

I need to replace all line breaks that are not preceded with two spaces, to achieve this:

`Hello world.  \nHello world.`

Here's a great solution, except that it doesn't work with safari <=15.1:

`str.replace(/(?<!\s\s)\n/g, "  \n");`

I've tried various solutions, all of which removed one or more characters from the preceding word. For example:

1. `/(^|[^ \t])\n/g`
2. `/(^|[^\n])(?:\n(?![ ]{2}))/g`

Comment: What if a line ends with one space? Should the result then really have **three** spaces, like will happen with the look-behind regex?

Comment: I didn't see much risk there. Essentially I need at least 2 spaces. An extra space isn't hurting anything.

Comment: Then why not prefix **all** newline characters with 2 spaces without any other condition?

Comment: I answered too soon. Looks like I have subsequent parsing that deals with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the capture group to the result with `$1` so those characters aren't removed.

```js
let string = 'Hello world.\nHello world1.  \nHello world2.';
let result = string.replace(/(^|\S)\n/g, '$1  \n');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Change "Hello world" to "Hello world from Barmar the great!" !

Comment: Hah that's great. Can you break down the regex for others please?

Comment: It's basically the same as your regexp. `\S` means non-whitespace, I used that in place of `[^ \t]`